# Unable to read the SharePoint List using java

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, soap, jax-ws, webservices-client

Here i am trying to read the list of sharepoint. For this i have done the following:
I have downloaded the WSDL file which i got from The URL like: sharepointsite.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL.
and i have executed the following command to generate the classes in the directory 
 “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\wsimport.exe” -p com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap -keep -extension Lists.wsdl. 
 Imported those classes in my eclipse IDE java application.

and i have written the following code

/* Creates a port connected to the SharePoint Web Service given.

```
 * Authentication is done here. It also prints the authentication details

 * in the console.

 * @param userName SharePoint username

 * @param password SharePoint password

 * @return port ListsSoap port, connected with SharePoint

 * @throws Exception in case of invalid parameters or connection error.

 */

public static ListsSoap sharePointListsAuth(String userName, String password) throws Exception {

    ListsSoap port = null;

    if (userName != null && password != null) {

        try {

            Lists service = new Lists();

            port = service.getListsSoap();

            System.out.println("Web Service Auth Username: " + userName);

            ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userName);

            ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new Exception("Error: " + e.toString());

        }

    } else {

        throw new Exception("Couldn't authenticate: Invalid connection details given.");

    }

    return port;

}
/**

 * Creates a string from an XML file with start and end indicators

 * @param docToString document to convert

 * @return string of the xml document

 */

public static String xmlToString(Document docToString) {

    String returnString = "\n-------------- XML START --------------\n";

    try {

        //create string from xml tree

        //Output the XML

        //set up a transformer

        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer trans;

        trans = transfac.newTransformer();

        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(sw);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(docToString);

        trans.transform(source, streamResult);

        String xmlString = sw.toString();

        //print the XML

        returnString = returnString + xmlString;

    } catch (TransformerException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

    returnString = returnString + "-------------- XML END --------------";

    return returnString;

}
/**
02
 * Connects to a SharePoint Lists Web Service through the given open port,
03
 * and reads all the elements of the given list. Only the ID and the given
04
 * attributes (column names) are displayed, as well as a dump of the SOAP
05
 * response from the Web Service (for debugging purposes).
06
 * @param port an already authentificated SharePoint Online SOAP port
07
 * @param listName original name of the Sharepoint list that is going to be read
08
 * @param listColumnNames arraylist containing the various names of the Columns
09
 * of the SharePoint list that are going to be read. If the column name isn't
10
 * found, then an exception will be thrown
11
 * @param rowLimit limits the number of rows (list items) that are going to
12
 * be returned
13
 * @throws Exception
14
 */

public static void displaySharePointList(ListsSoap port, String listName, ArrayList<String> listColumnNames, String rowLimit) throws Exception {

    if (port != null && listName != null && listColumnNames != null && rowLimit != null) {

        try {



            //Here are additional parameters that may be set

            String viewName = "";

            GetListItems.ViewFields viewFields = null;

            GetListItems.Query query = null;

            GetListItems.QueryOptions queryOptions = null;

            String webID = "";



            //Calling the List Web Service

            GetListItemsResponse.GetListItemsResult result = port.getListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, webID);

            Object listResult = result.getContent().get(0);

            if ((listResult != null) && (listResult instanceof ElementNSImpl)) {

                ElementNSImpl node = (ElementNSImpl) listResult;



                //Dumps the retrieved info in the console

                Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();

                System.out.println("SharePoint Online Lists Web Service Response:" + Manager.xmlToString(document));



                //selects a list of nodes which have z:row elements

                NodeList list = node.getElementsByTagName("z:row");

                System.out.println("=> " + list.getLength() + " results from SharePoint Online");



                //Displaying every result received from SharePoint, with its ID

                for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {


                    //Gets the attributes of the current row/element

                    NamedNodeMap attributes = list.item(i).getAttributes();

                    System.out.println("******** Item ID: " + attributes.getNamedItem("ows_ID").getNodeValue()+" ********");



                    //Displays all the attributes of the list item that correspond to the column names given

                    for (String columnName : listColumnNames) {

                        String internalColumnName = "ows_" + columnName;

                        if (attributes.getNamedItem(internalColumnName) != null) {

                            System.out.println(columnName + ": " + attributes.getNamedItem(internalColumnName).getNodeValue());

                        } else {

                            throw new Exception("Couldn't find the '" + columnName + "' column in the '" + listName + "' list in SharePoint.\n");

                        }

                    }

                }

            } else {

                throw new Exception(listName + " list response from SharePoint is either null or corrupt\n");

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            throw new Exception("Exception. See stacktrace." + ex.toString() + "\n");

        }

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {



            //Authentication parameters

            String userName = "domain\\username";

            String password = "pass";



            //Opening the SOAP port of the Lists Web Service

            ListsSoap port = Manager.sharePointListsAuth(userName, password);



            /*

             * Lists Web service parameters

             * The list names below must be the *original* names of the list.

             * if a list or column was renamed from SharePoint afterwards,

             * these parameters don't change.

             */

            String listName = "listname";

            String rowLimit = "2";

            ArrayList<String> listColumnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            listColumnNames.add("Name");

            listColumnNames.add("ID");

            //Displays the lists items in the console

            Manager.displaySharePointList(port, listName, listColumnNames, rowLimit);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.err.println(ex);

        }

    }
```

I am getting following exception :

Web Service Auth Username: "domain\username"
java.lang.Exception: Exception. See stacktrace.javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.

```
    It would be helpfull if i get the specific exception from the server.With this expection i am unable to track my pgm. 
    I dont know where did i go wrong?  am i missing anything ?  any configuration is required ?

    Thanks in advance for your help
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try with an Authenticator :

```
new BasicAuthentication(userName,password).authenticate();
```

My BasicAuthentication class :

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class BasicAuthentication extends Authenticator
{
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public BasicAuthentication(String username, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(username,password.toCharArray()));
    }

    public void authenticate()
    {
        Authenticator.setDefault(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not getting authentication success, its same error 401, need help @Mathieu Colin

Comment: Do you know the type of Authentication your SharePoint server has been configured for?  BasicAuth will not work if Windows Authentication has been selected, also if you can use Kerberos, this is generally easier to get working than NTLM outside of MS implementations.